# How can update data associated in a row on KeyPress in a SPGridView?

Tags: 2010, visual-studio

*This should be pretty easy but I can't find it anywhere.*

Scenario: `DataTable` associated to an `SPGridView`. Every row of the `SPGridView` is editable and it shows boxes on some of the columns. I put an Update button and I implemented the RowUpdating event which works perfectly.

So, what I want is when the user press the Intro key in the TextBox, this action launch the Update command.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `SPGridView` is nothing more then basic `GridView` with some additions maybe this link can be helpful (at least as starting point):

[Handling the Enter key pressed in a GridView's row edit mode](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38579/Handling-the-Enter-key-pressed-in-a-GridView-s-row)

```
protected void gvChild_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // if enter key is pressed (keycode==13) call __doPostBack on grid and with 
    // 1st param = gvChild.UniqueID (Gridviews UniqueID)
    // 2nd param = CommandName=Update$  +  CommandArgument=RowIndex
    if ((e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit) || 
       (e.Row.RowState == (DataControlRowState.Edit|DataControlRowState.Alternate)))
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) { 
            __doPostBack('" + gvChild.UniqueID + "', 'Update$" + 
           e.Row.RowIndex.ToString() + "'); return false; }");
    } 
}
```

I never tested this code so here is little disclaimer:

Specific SP problems can arise on page postback. I am not sure about `gvChild.UniqueID` part of the sample code. I think [Control.ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) suits better.

Comment: I changed a little bit, but it worked like a charm. Instead of generating the `__doPostBack` function manually I call to `String sPostBackScript = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.gvChild, "Update$" + e.Row.RowIndex);`. But it was really helpful, thanks. PS: Remember put `AutoPostBack="False"`.